# React-Native TextInput multiline, switch to next input, do not want to add new line

Tags: react-native, newline, multiline, textinput, onsubmit

I suspect that I may not be able to do this at the moment.. but it doesn't hurt to ask for some ideas! I have multiple multiline TextInputs on a single page, that I would like to be able to use the "next" button in order to switch to the next TextInput.

I can switch inputs without issue, however... I have to choose between using "blurOnSubmit" - which does not add a new line, but it does dismiss the keyboard. This makes the android experience really poor when the next input is focused. It does the same for iOS, but iOS handles it a little better.

Or, I can not use blurOnSubmit, and then I need to ensure I update the state myself to manually remove the '\n' that is added...

Does anyone have a better solution?

A typical page looks something like this (cleared all decoration and view vs edit logic):

```
<View>
<TextInput
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    multiline={true}
    onChangeText={(valueA) => this.setState({ valueA })}
    onSubmitEditing={() => this._onSubmitEditing(this.refs.B)}
    returnKeyType={"next"}
    value={this.state.valueA}
    ref="A"
/>
<TextInput
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    multiline={true}
    onChangeText={(valueB) => this.setState({ valueB })}
    onSubmitEditing={() => this._onSubmitEditing(this.refs.C)}
    returnKeyType={"next"}
    value={this.state.valueB}
    ref="B"
/>
<TextInput
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    multiline={true}
    onChangeText={(valueC) => this.setState({ valueC })}
    onSubmitEditing={this._validateAndSave}
    returnKeyType={"done"}
    value={this.state.valueC}
    ref="C"
/>
</View>
```

Related Function:

```
    _onSubmitEditing (nextRef) {
        if(!!nextRef && nextRef.focus) {
            nextRef.focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Came here since I had `TextInput` was adding a newline when hitting `done`.

In your `TextInput` add:
`blurOnSubmit={true}`
or just
`blurOnSubmit`.

Default value for single-line fields is `true`, but, for multiline fields it's `false`.

Found here: https://github.com/wix/react-native-autogrow-textinput/issues/25#issuecomment-328243174